# How can I prevent inactivity log outs on websites?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

I use a couple of websites which log me out after being inactive with the browser window open for more than a couple of minutes. This gets really annoying, I have to type my password in, do 2FA on my phone again or even email, multiple times a day. I have been thinking about a chrome extension I could use to prevent this. My idea is to send a mouse click to the corner of the page every three minutes, if I can find out how to do that using javascript without disturbing my own browsing. I am asking here because I was wondering whether someone knows,

1. How likely this is to work and how it could be implemented given that google chrome extensions don't have hardware access
2. If there is a better approach I could use or an existing solution

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is fit for Stack Overflow (it might be though, I'm not very familiar with the rules myself). If it is, then I suggest inspecting the page and removing the offending JavaScript code (it should be relatively easy to find, just look for a `setTimeout` function call or something)

Comment: There are several extensions on store which do what you're asking for.
Search something like: "KeepmeAlive" or similar.
If you want to develop your own extension you can design it this way.
Ping those sites that kick you out more often than the session logout time.
How to do this ping?
Simply fetching (FETCH or XHR) in the extension background any page beyond the sign-in page.